# How to change the position after disabling visibility of the widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter. I'm displaying the cards based on the list of items. By using switch button I am trying to show only the Priority items. When switch is "ON" I need to display Only Priority items, while it's OFF I need to display the entire list of items.

I have achieved this using Switch and Visibility widget, but the position of the cards didn't change.
Here is What I have done so far,

Code:

For passing the list items,

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const curveHeight = 15.0;

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Text(dashboardTitle),
          shape: const MyShapeBorder(curveHeight),
          leading: Switch(
            value: isSwitched,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                isSwitched = value;
                dashboardTitle =
                    (isSwitched) ? 'Priority Alerts' : 'All Alerts';
                showPriority = (isSwitched) ? true : false;
              });
            },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.red[400],
            activeColor: Colors.red[600],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(IconData(0xe848, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons')),
              onPressed: () async {
                await removeWorkManager();
                await logout();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                color: Colors.red[200],
                child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: CurvePainter(),
                    child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
                      return FutureBuilder<List<Choice>>(
                        future: choices,
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            return GridView.builder(
                                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                gridDelegate:
                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount:
                                      orientation == Orientation.portrait
                                          ? 2
                                          : 4,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                                ),
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                                  //  print(snapshot.data[index]);
                                  return Center(
                                    child: SelectCard(
                                        choice: snapshot.data[index]),
                                  );
                                });
                          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            print(snapshot);
                            return Text("Error");
                          }
                          return Text("Loading...");
                        },
                      );
                    })))));
```

Here is Card Creation class,

```
class _SelectCard extends State<SelectCard> {
  bool loading = false;
  double progress = 0;

  final Choice choice;

  _SelectCard(this.choice);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle titleStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 15.0,
        color: new Color(int.parse(choice.colors)));
    final TextStyle alertStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0, color: Colors.black);
    final TextStyle messageStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.green[800]);

    bool showOperator = false;

    if (showPriority) {
      if (choice.priority == '1') {
        showOperator = false;
      } else {
        showOperator = true;
      }
    }
    return Visibility(
        visible: showOperator,
        child: Container(
            child: Card(
          elevation: 20,
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            choice.title,
                            style: titleStyle,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Text(
                            choice.alertName,
                            style: alertStyle,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 5),
                          Text(
                            choice.alertMessage,
                            style: messageStyle,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )));
  }
}


I have also tried with Offstage widget, but the result was same. Sorry, I can't able post my screen shot directly because of my low reputation points.
```

[My Full List items screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvV8f.png)&
[My Priority list item screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRa8m.png).

As you can see in the above pictures ,when I am displaying the priority items, it displays the card in the second position while it should be first.

Any help would be great!. Thanks in advance.